# Multiple lines for each point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I wish to generate lines between some circles (or in this case, some corners of circles), such that on hovering over one circle you would see lines pointing to all the other circles. My problem is that I cannot seem to find how I can use d3 to access the relevant parts of `points` for each circle/group.

I believe I either need to change the datastructure of `points` or use d3's `each`, but I don't see how it can be done. Below is a working example, but from the last 24 lines of code it should be obvious that this isn't (or shouldn't) be scalable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  line{opacity: 0.0;stroke : blue;}
  g:hover line{opacity: 1.0;}
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.15/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width",  500)
      .attr("height", 500)

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range([0, 500]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range([500, 0]);

    d3.csv('input_data.csv', function(error,data){
      if (error) throw error;

      var circles = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data).enter().append("g")
        .attr("id",function(d,i){return "group"+i;})
        .append("circle")
        .attr('cx',function(d){return x(d.x);})
        .attr('cy',function(d){return y(d.y);})
        .attr('r',50);  

      //generating points which I want to connect with one line
      //per 2 xy coordinates
      var points = [];
      for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){    
        points.push([])
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          points[i].push(
            {'xval':[data[i].x,data[j].x],
            'yval':[data[i].y,data[j].y]}
          );
        }
      }
      //attempt at drawing some of these lines
      svg.selectAll("#group0").selectAll("line")
        .data(points).enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1",function(d,i){return x(d[0].xval[0]);})
        .attr("x2",function(d,i){return x(d[0].xval[1]);})
        .attr("y1",function(d,i){return y(d[0].yval[0]);})
        .attr("y2",function(d,i){return y(d[0].yval[1]);});
      svg.selectAll("#group1").selectAll("line")
        .data(points).enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1",function(d,i){return x(d[1].xval[0]);})
        .attr("x2",function(d,i){return x(d[1].xval[1]);})
        .attr("y1",function(d,i){return y(d[1].yval[0]);})
        .attr("y2",function(d,i){return y(d[1].yval[1]);});
      svg.selectAll("#group2").selectAll("line")
        .data(points).enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1",function(d,i){return x(d[2].xval[0]);})
        .attr("x2",function(d,i){return x(d[2].xval[1]);})
        .attr("y1",function(d,i){return y(d[2].yval[0]);})
        .attr("y2",function(d,i){return y(d[2].yval[1]);});
      svg.selectAll("#group3").selectAll("line")
        .data(points).enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1",function(d,i){return x(d[3].xval[0]);})
        .attr("x2",function(d,i){return x(d[3].xval[1]);})
        .attr("y1",function(d,i){return y(d[3].yval[0]);})
        .attr("y2",function(d,i){return y(d[3].yval[1]);});

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

This code should be a(n almost) minimal standalone example of what I want given the file `input_data.csv`:

```
x,y
0.5,1.0
0.0,0.5
1.0,0.5
0.5,0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping with your current methodology, how about:

```
  circles.each(function(d0){
    var self = this;
    var group = d3.select(self.parentNode);
    circles.each(function(d1){
      if (self !== this){
        group.append("line")
          .attr("x1",function(d,i){return x(d0.x);})
          .attr("x2",function(d,i){return x(d1.x);})
          .attr("y1",function(d,i){return y(d0.y);})
          .attr("y2",function(d,i){return y(d1.y);});
      }
    });
```

Full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/73rqhnx4TbBsYX5h5vAn?p=preview).

---

Instead of pre-drawing all the lines you might want to think about drawing them on mouseover and removing them on mouseout.  As the number of points scales up it'll probably be easier on memory.  This would look like:

```
    // draw circles...
    .on('mouseover', function(d0){
      var self = this;
      var group = d3.select(self.parentNode);
      circles.each(function(d1){
        if (self !== this){
          group.append("line")
            .attr("x1",function(d,i){return x(d0.x);})
            .attr("x2",function(d,i){return x(d1.x);})
            .attr("y1",function(d,i){return y(d0.y);})
            .attr("y2",function(d,i){return y(d1.y);});
        }
      });
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d){
      var self = this;
      var group = d3.select(self.parentNode);
      group.selectAll('line').remove();
    });
```

Full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZA25TSvt3gmtdc66sgCV?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. On a side note, does "keeping with your current methodology" refer to me pre-drawing it, or does it imply you would have done things otherwise? If so, what sticks out as being poor code?

Comment: @M.T, I was referring to the pre-drawing.  See updates to answer to doing it on mouseover and out.